Tengo marcado dos errores en php que no consigo descifrar, están en la llamada Mail y PEAR
Estoy intentando enviar un correo desde una página web, tras el proceso de un formulario, pero no consigo que el mismo llegue.
<?php
    require_once "Mail.php";
    $from = "algalan@easytic.es";
    $to = "algalanperez@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
    $host = "smtp.servidor-correo.net"; // sin "ssl://"
    $port = "465"; // Puerto para SSL
    $username = "algalan@easytic.es";
    $password = "?????";
    $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array (
        'host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    ));

    if (PEAR::isError($smtp)) {
        die('Error en la configuración de SMTP: ' . $smtp->getMessage());
    }

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo(' ' . $mail->getMessage() . ' ');
    } else {
        echo('Message successfully sent!');
    }
?>

He recibido este código desde mi hosting, pero no consigo que funcione.

Buenas, Antonio, bienvenido al sitio. ¿Le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? ¿Cuáles son los errores exactamente y en qué lineas se producen?

¿Y qué dicen los erores? ¿Qué versión de Pear::Mail? En el parámetro $smtp coloca temporalmente 'debug' => true para ver la salida completa y tener una pista de dónde se está quedando la ejecución.
